# How to change email template date format

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

change date format from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in netsuite email template. I want to show date a dd/mm/yy format to show on netsuite email template

Original-${transaction.trandate}

Currently I am getting trandate as mm/dd/yyyy

I want format as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: when I use this ${transaction.trandate?string["dd.MM.yyyy"]}

why I am getting error as, The template cannot be saved due to the following errors:
Syntax error in template “content” in line 1, column 36:. Encountered “&”, but was expecting one of these patterns:. <RAW_STRING>. “false”. “true”. <INTEGER>.
“”””. “T”. “C”. “C”. <ID>
Parse exception during template merging.
<STRING_LITERAL>. <DECIMAL>.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Netsuite tries to convert your freemarker tags to xml when you save a template in visual mode

e.g. `${transaction.trandate?string["dd.MM.yyyy"]}` is saved something like: `${transaction.trandate?string[&quot;dd.MM.yyyy&quot;]}`

If you save the template in source view mode you should be good.

One process you can follow is:
Copy the template, in source view, out to a 'proper' text editor (e.g., vs code, sublime text, notepad++, textpad) . Make sure all the inappropriate xml conversions have been put back to Freemarker code and then paste it back in. DO NOT use visual mode in Netsuite any more.

You may be able to use Netsuite's editor if you wrap your problematic freemarker in CDATA sections. I have not tried this but if your users can't stop saving in visual mode then it may be worth a shot.

```xml
<[CDATA[${transaction.trandate?string["dd.MM.yyyy"]}]]>
```

Comment: I tried that but then also same error occurs

Comment: see my updated answer. You may have missed a conversion.